# Is there any tool for eclipse or as CLI which can create repositories for JPA Entity Classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-mvc, code-generation

I have lot of JPA Entity Classes and I have to write service and repository classes for all Entities, Manually it may take lot of time to write each and everything from scratch.

I have Create Entities with JPA Tools (an eclipse plugin to generate entity classes from table and vice versa) and cross checked the columns in DB and properties in entity classes are correctly mapped. I saw [JPA Buddy](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-buddy) but it is an intelliJ idea plugin and many of good features are paid. I need something related to Eclipse or ping name if there is a CLI tool too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of need you can use Telosys code generator ( https://www.telosys.org/ ) that's exactly what it was created for.

There are bundles of templates for JPA (and other targets : Spring, controllers, services, etc )

See also this answer : [What are the best Java code generation tools or plugins to use in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360282/what-are-the-best-java-code-generation-tools-or-plugins-to-use-in-eclipse)
and the documentation : https://doc.telosys.org/

Comment: how we can generate only services and repositories if we already have Entity classes by referring those entity classes

Comment: In a bundle of templates (templates.cfg file) you just have to remove (delete or comment) the lines concerning the templates you don't want to use (.vm files for entities generation).

Comment: this will even not generate code from my existing entities but it will deprecated entity classes Generation